# Dinamically update text boxes in with PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm pretty new to this world, so sorry if the question sounds weird.

I've made a simple UI with QtDesigner, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

What I'm trying to do without success is to update the Y box values depending on the X values added, when the checkbox is checked.

That's just a piece of the code:

```
self.defaultRes=float(10)
        self.sboxXres.setValue(self.defaultRes)
        self.sboxYres.setValue(self.defaultRes)


    #  ======= Update automatically when 1:1 ratio is checked
    def set_Yres(self, value):
        if self.checkRatio.isChecked():
            self.sboxYres.setValue(value)
```

but, with this code, the Y won't update..

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: You need to show more code. How is the `set_Yres()` method being called? Have to connected it to a signal?

Comment: The code could be very long (it's a part of an external plugin).. ``set_Yres`` is just the function I have created for updating the text box..

Comment: I didn't say post the whole code of your entire application. But you need to post all the relevant parts. Saying "my tiny bit of code doesn't work" isn't helpful if you don't show how the code is called. How can we help you debug without more context? "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself... See: How to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use signals to do this. When you change your X value you will send a signal which will be catch by your setY method and do the job.

Go check it => [PyQt combobox documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html)

[Signal example](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)